# not able to import datetime package

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-datetime

I have a code and it is giving me the error:

```
ImportError: cannot import name datetime
```

My code is:

```
from datetime import datetime as dt
import time

while True:
if dt.now().second in range(0, 30):  #start, stop are integers (eg: 6, 9)
    # call to your scheduled task goes here
    print "Yes " + str(dt.now().year) +" : "+ str(dt.now().month) +" : "+ str(dt.now().day) + str(dt.now().hour) +" : "+ str(dt.now().minute) +" : "+ str(dt.now().second)
    time.sleep(10)  # Minimum interval between task executions
else:
    print "No " + str(dt.now().hour) +" : "+ str(dt.now().minute) +" : "+ str(dt.now().second)
    time.sleep(10)  # The else clause is not necessary but would prevent the program to keep the CPU busy.
```

Comment: What does `import datetime; print datetime.__file__` tell you is imported instead? You almost certainly have another module with the same name masking the standard library.

Comment: What's the name of *your* module?

Comment: If you look at the error traceback it will almost certainly be pointing to your own `datetime.py` you have created.

Comment: Please paste the _full_ error traceback into a new code block in your question. Also, the indentation of your code is incorrect.

Comment: My problem is resolved. The error was the module name and program name was the same.